# File Upload google app engine blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

I am going to use Google app engine Blobstore to store my uploaded files. File type can be anything (.txt,.pdf,.docx etc)
I have written following servlet to download stored files in Google app engine Blobstore.

```
public class Serve extends HttpServlet { 

private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
```

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws IOException {

```
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);      

}
```

}

But every time I request a file by giving a url as below,
http://127.0.0.1:8888/serve?blob-key=DEHQ3U_2wtUdEL7XPI434Q
file is downloaded nicely. But no extension for file. And name of the file is always ‘serve’
What should I do to download the uploaded file with the original name of the file?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know python has a `send_as` option that automatically sets the filename for the response, but I think in Java you will have to add a `Content-Disposition` header to the response like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your-file.docx;
```

The BlobInfo for your blob keeps the original filename and you can fetch it via `getFilename`

Comment: Yes. I can set the header if I know the file name.But is there any method to get the file name of a stored file using blob key?

Comment: each Blobstore "blob" has a related `BlobInfo` entity, which can be fetched with the blob-key. The BlobInfo entity stores the original filename of the uploaded file, which can be accessed via [`getFilename`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfo.html#getFilename())

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code to serve a blob by passing the blob-key as a String to my Serve.java .  File is downloaded using the original filename as well as the original extension.  Found a more detailed discussion at http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index3.html

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobInfoFactory bi = new BlobInfoFactory();
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
String fname = bi.loadBlobInfo(blobKey).getFilename();
res.setContentType("application/x-download");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```